# Why devices connected through phone's tethering are are in a different network

Tags: wireless-networking, android, tethering

My desktop pc is without a wifi card and is connected to the wifi through an Usb to my phone which is connected to the wifi (classic tethering usb).

This place my desktop in the 192.168.56.x/24 subnet, instead of the usual 192.168.1.x/24 where all my other devices connected directly to wifi are.

My goal is to have the desktop pc in the 192.168.1.x/24 network.

I fear the configuration necessary is within my phone but I couldn't find it in my phone settings.
I would be happy to provide additional information if needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tethering, the phone always acts as a router. This is deliberate – bridging would be completely impossible for 4G/LTE uplinks (which is the primary use case of tethering, after all), but it would also create additional headaches even if you're using a Wi-Fi uplink.

As usual, the problem with bridging regular Wi-Fi is that a connected device can only have *one* MAC address (the same one that was used to establish the association), so when your desktop sends out some Ethernet packets, the phone cannot simply forward them to Wi-Fi as-is – it would need to rewrite them with its own MAC address, then recognize packets sent *to* the computer's IP and do the opposite rewriting, etc.

(Basically, the bridge would need to NAT at Ethernet level. Unlike IP NAT, however – which Android gets for free due to it being built-in to Linux – Ethernet NAT *isn't* natively supported by the kernel, meaning Android would need to have it done from scratch.)

Dedicated wireless bridges ("wifi extenders") have additional code to deal with this problem, i.e. they *do* either implement Ethernet NAT as described, or (as I've been told) create a separate Wi-Fi connection for every new device they detect on the "wired" side.

But extenders do this because that's their *primary* purpose – whereas tethering mode in a cellphone probably isn't designed with Wi-Fi connection in mind at all, so it's probably *much* simpler for Android developers to implement IP routing with "normal" NAT instead (especially given that they'd need to do it *anyway* for LTE, even if they did the work to make bridging available for Wi-Fi).

TL;DR: There is no configuration for this. Either get a Wi-Fi USB adapter, or a Wi-Fi PCIe expansion card, or one of those "extenders" (they often have exactly the mode you want).