# how enable communication between devices in different subnets

Tags: wireless-networking, router, subnet

In the scenario described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1734893/why-devices-connected-through-phones-tethering-are-are-in-a-different-network):
How can a device on 192.168.252.x/24 see and communicate with a device on 192.168.1.x/24?

I'm trying to add a route so my router redirects packets for 192.168.252.x to the Ip my phone has in the 192.168.1.x/24 network but it doesn't seem it suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct in general – but in your case routes won't suffice because the 'router' (your tethering phone) has a firewall set up preventing communications inwards. As far as I know, Android's tethering mode *always* does this (it even blocks communications between USB tethering clients and wireless hotspot clients), and I don't think you can disable it, at least not without rooting the phone.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that a device connected to the internet through tethering usb is completely undetectable from outside the network? This would prevent any attempt of intrusion from a security standpoint, right?

Comment: It would prevent _network-based_ intrusions... though I doubt that it would be considerably better at it than the computer's existing OS-based firewall. But it wouldn't prevent other common attacks such as web-browser exploits.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is for the router to be defined with a netmask of
`255.255.0.0`.

The router would then serve both segments as belonging to
`192.168.x.x/16` and would transfer messages from one to the other.

If this doesn't work for your network, more information would be required
on your network architecture, such as how IP addresses are allocated in
both segments.

Comment: In my router, configuring my local network, I setted the subnet mask as 255.255.0.0 but it says the Gateway IP (192.168.1.1)  should not be in sfp IP Range

Comment: Ensure that `192.168.1.1` is not within the range for allocating IP addresses.

Comment: For this to work, "both segments" would need to become _one_ segment, with no routing in between – if they remain separate, with a router in between, then the subnet mask would be telling the router to do exactly the wrong thing.